# Witten's "Semiclassical Stability of Minkowski Space" versus Christodoulou and Klainerman's "Global Nonlinear Stability of the Minkowski Space"

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vacuum

At least naively, there seems to be a tension between two seminal works on the stability of Minkowski space.

In Witten's [A New Proof of the Positive Energy Theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-80/issue-3/A-new-proof-of-the-positive-energy-theorem/cmp/1103919981.full), in the section "Semiclassical Stability of Minkowski Space," Witten considers the vacuum Einstein equation of $R_{\mu \nu} = 0$ and an asymptotically Euclidean metric $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + a_{ij}$ where $a_{ij} \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$. Witten argues that the only such asymptotically Euclidean space satisfying $R_{\mu \nu} = 0$ is flat Euclidean space.

On the other hand, Christodoulou and Klainerman in [Global Nonlinear Stability of the Minkowski Space](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7zthns) write in the introductuion that their work "provides a constructive proof of global, smooth, nontrivial solutions to the Einstein-Vacuum equations, which look, in the large, like the Minkowski space-time." That is, they are constructing non-trivial solutions to the vacuum equation of $R_{\mu \nu} = 0$ that "look Minkowski" at large distance scales. I learned of this work in [an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/786469) to a related question of mine, but I haven't yet fully absorbed it (nor Witten's work).

How do I reconcile these results, one ruling out nontrivial solutions and the other constructing them? As far as I can see, the main difference is that Witten considers an asymptotically Euclidean (rather than Minkowski) space. Perhaps that is actually enough to change the story? Or is there some other fundamental difference between the works?

Comment: Euclidean vs. Lorentzian. Big difference. As a simpler example, take the wave equation $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ with the boundary conditions $\phi \to 0$ as $|x| \to 0$. This has no solutions in Euclidean signature, but wave solutions exist in Lorentzian signature.

Comment: @stringynonsense That's a good example. One curious thing: Your example considers two different differential equations with the same boundary conditions, while the problem in my question involves two choices of boundary conditions for a fixed differential equation. Or are they more analogous than I realize?

Comment: They are exactly analogous! Einstein's equations (EFE) in Euclidean vs. Lorentzian signature are different (just like the wave equation). The only difference is that Einstein's equations are highly non-linear, so reaching conclusions of the sort that Witten and CK did is not an easy task. I've had CKs book on nonlinear stability in my library for 5 years and I still don't understand a lot of what they have done!